# When were replicas of Green Lantern's Power Battery and Power Ring first produced?

Tags: dc, history-of, green-lantern

The earliest replicas of Power Battery and Power Ring I've seen were released in 2002. As Green Lantern exist since 1940 I have a question: were there replicas of the above named items like in 50s, 70s of 20 century? And were at that time any collectibles at all?

I'll be very grateful for any information.

Answer (score 2):

They made giveaway lantern rings as a promo for the first issue of Green Lantern Mosaic in 1992

[image]

The bit in the middle glows in the dark.